# Автоматизировать документацию в Postman

Tags: postman

Мне нравится работать в Postman и я ищу способ, как улучшить взаимодействие с ним. Мне нужно, чтобы написанные в сторонних программах спецификации OpenAPI 3.0.0 попадали в Postman через git репозиторий и дальше опубликовались в виде документации. Вот что я сейчас делаю для этого:

0. Редактирую schemas/index.yaml и отправляю в репозиторий
1. Дальше всё в Postman. Вкладка Source Control справа
2. Нажимаю на кнопку Pull changes
3. Выбираю API ПКМ и нажимаю Add collection - Generate from definition
4. На созданной коллекции ПКМ - Copy to workspace
5. Во вкладке Collections для созданной коллекции ПКМ - View documentation
6. Publish

На выходе получаю ссылку вида https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/123456/123456abc#intro , которую отправляю тем, кто пользуется этим API.

Можно ли эти шаги автоматизировать? Или это большой костыль и мне стоит смотреть в сторону других сервисов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перешёл на https://stoplight.io . Он предоставляет весь необходимый мне функционал и умеет автоматически синхронизировать документацию с гитом.